# Average percentage change over different years in R

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

I have a data frame from which I created a reproducible example:

```
country <- c('A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C')
year <- c(2010,2011,2015,2008,2009,2008,2009,2011,2015)
score <- c(1,2,2,1,4,1,1,3,2)

  country year score
1       A 2010     1
2       A 2011     2
3       A 2015     2
4       B 2008     1
5       B 2009     4
6       C 2008     1
7       C 2009     1
8       C 2011     3
9       C 2015     2
```

And I am trying to calculate the average percentage increase (or decrease) in the score for each country by calculating [(final score - initial score) ÷ (initial score)] for each year and averaging it over the number of years.

```
 country year score  change
1       A 2010     1     NA
2       A 2011     2      1
3       A 2015     2      0
4       B 2008     1     NA
5       B 2009     4      3
6       C 2008     1     NA
7       C 2009     1      0
8       C 2011     3      2
9       C 2015     2  -0.33
```

The final result I am hoping to obtain:

```
  country  avg_change
1       A         0.5
2       B           3
3       C        0.55
```

As you can see, the trick is that countries have spans over different years, sometimes with a missing year in between. I tried different ways to do it manually but I do struggle. If someone could hint me a solution would be great. Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `country` and get `mean` of difference between `scores`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarise(avg_change = mean(c(NA, diff(score)), na.rm = TRUE))

# country avg_change
#  <fct>        <dbl>
#1  A            0.500
#2  B            3.00 
#3  C            0.333
```

---

Using base R `aggregate` with same logic

```
aggregate(score~country, df, function(x) mean(c(NA, diff(x)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table` to group by 'country' and take the `mean` of the difference between the 'score' and the `lag` of 'score'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(avg_change = mean(score -lag(score), na.rm = TRUE)), .(country)]
#   country avg_change
#1:       A  0.5000000
#2:       B  3.0000000
#3:       C  0.3333333
```